# Is it possible to update a label embedded in a formveiw?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am thinking that I already have the answer to this question based on my own simulations and tests but I so much want to do this and it would be so useful for my page that I would like to get it to work that I'm going to toss it out here for the rest of you to see if maybe someone has figured out a practical way to accomplish what I've failed to find a way to do thus far.

Scenario:
Take an `<asp:FormView>` which is data driven and of course you have data elements which you can manipulate in the form to position according to your desire within the form.

Now What I did was opt to add to this a static DDL which I can collect values from and change the value of one of the fields in the FormView. This works well.

For the finishing touch what I would like to add to this is add a `<asp:Label>` (which was not generated by the datasource) and alter that label based on the value selected chosen on the drop down list. ie. this would be a narrative for the value being selected.

Problem:
What I have discovered is that I can't treat the `<asp:Label>` I inserted into the FormView in the same way that I would one that was created by the datasource. This kinda surprised me as I can address the DDL and pull values from it but I don't seem to be able to write a text value to my `<asp:Label>` that I've created inside of the `<FormView>`.

It really will not help much but here is the code that I thought should work but didn't:

```
// This line pulls the value that I want to place in the label
Label astylbl = (Label)GetAssetTypeFV.Row.FindControl("AssetTypeLabel");

// This sequence should be setting the value collect above into the label 
// NOTE! That the Label has been prepopulated with data to make sure it isn't 

Label ATTL = (Label)GetAssetTypeFV.Row.FindControl("AssetTypeTextLabel");
  if (ATTL != null)
      ATTL.Text = astylbl.Text;
```

Now is this simply an impossibility or am I missing something here?

Comment: Is the AssetTypeTextLabel being set/instantiated elsewhere, causing it to reset when selecting an item from the DDL due to form submission, or is it being handled as an ajax call?

Comment: No it is just that instance of it. I could flow it for you if it would be helpful.

Comment: May need to post add'l code.  Need to know what events are firing in general.

Comment: My bad... My code works fine... (except for the fact that I was referencing the wrong FV name).  After correcting that everything was perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The corrected code looks like this:

```
Label astylbl = (Label)GetAssetTypeFV.Row.FindControl("AssetTypeLabel");
Label ATTL = (Label)ChangeFormFV.Row.FindControl("AssetTypeTextLabel");
  if (ATTL != null)
      ATTL.Text = astylbl.Text;
```

All is well now!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign the label on the client side (without form validation) you should do it with whatever client-side scripting you're using (javascript, jquery, etc).

Otherwise, you need to have the DDL post-back by setting `AutoPostBack="True"` on the target DDL control and handle it on the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event.

Edit:
If you want to handle it on the server side, and not reload the page, you'll have to do that by creating a `[WebMethod]` function in the code-behind, and call it with using AJAX.